# Can ajax be used for faceting/sorting?

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, facet

I created a select from with popularity,high_to_low and low_to_high as options. I want the page to respond to these options dynamically using the ajax code

```
var http_option = createRequestObject();

function verifyRequest() 
   {
     var option = document.getElementById("option").value;
     if ( option ) 
       {
       var url = 'respond.pl?option='+option;
       http_option.open('get', url );
       http_option.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
       http_option.send(null);
       }
   }     

function handleResponse() 
   {
       if(http_option.readyState == 4 && http_option.status == 200)
       {
       var response = http_option.responseText; // Text returned FROM perl script
       if(response) { // UPDATE ajaxTest content
       document.getElementById("id_id").innerHTML = response;  
       }
   }
```

If the value of the option is 1, images are displayed as stored in DB.
If the option is 2, images are to be displayed in descending order and
If the option is 3, images are to be displayed in ascending  order

The respond.pl contain appropriate code for this sorting according to options and display images in a specified div tag. 
The problem is that the page responds to the options only once and the next time on changing the option, the value of options shows "on" and not the numerals 1,2,3

I need this not only to sort images but also for faceting. If this is not the right option suggest the appropriate methods used for it.

Comment: If you get "on" you probably have a check box input without the "value" attribute

Comment: That is the problem. The respond.pl code contain a checkbox for which i applied the ajax calling method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server-side program is returning HTML. And I think that's probably a mistake in this situation. I suggest returning JSON instead. Then, you can create an onChange event handler for your selector which simply re-orders the display. There are almost certainly a number of jQuery plugins that do this without you needing to write very much code.